# Why "[I am] just like him" is correct not "just like he"

Tags: grammar

"Him" is an object pronoun. In grammar, we use the word "object" to talk about the thing or person that the verb is done to, or who receives the verb. I don't understand how a verb that is not an action but a condition can have an object.

Comment: "Him" is not object of the verb but object complement of the preposition "like".

Comment: The form "*I am not like he **is***" is pretty rare in my view but plausible.

Comment: I use "like him" when I am using the other guy as a reference point, a way for the audience better to understand who I am because I am like someone they already know.  In contrast, I use "as he is" to claim mere commonality in some regard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Object" pronouns are not just used for the objects of verbs. They have various other uses; one common use of objective pronouns is for objects of prepositions. "Like" is often analyzed as a preposition in this context.

*Like* can also be used as a "conjunction", but there is a "traditional" aversion in prescriptivist sources to the use of *like* as a conjunction (see e.g. [Should we use "like" as a conjunction?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/100605/should-we-use-like-as-a-conjunction)). It's kind of the opposite of the situation with *than,* where the "traditional" prescriptivist position is that *than* should only be used as a conjunction and not as a preposition.